# Setting a Sharepoint Site Theme through a Web Service?

Tags: sharepoint

Is it possible to change a Sharepoint 2007 Site Theme through a Web Service? I know it can be done through the Object Model with (i think) SPWeb.ApplyTheme, but I did not see anything in the available Web Services, apart from CustomizeCss in Webs.asmx, which does not seem to be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible out of the box. However, you can write your own custom SharePoint web service that exposes this feature to you. A walkthrough on how to make your own custom web service in SharePoint can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx

Another way would be to create your own themesetter and invoke it via a request. An example of this can be found here:

http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2006/03/automatically-applying-theme-to-site.html