# Accessing Sharepoint Data through Web Services in Asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, web-services, sharepoint

We have 2 different sites, one is Asp.net and another MS Sharepoint and we need to take some data from Sharepoint to the Asp.net site

The Asp.net application is one server and the Sharepoint Site is on a different server.

How can we do move that from one site to another through Web-services?

We are looking for suggestions.

Comment: Please improve your question with:
-Version of Asp.net framework;
-Version of MSSharepoint;
-What kind of data you need to move;
-What are the options you know off.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard Sharepoint soap web services or Managed client object model. Please find links below:

Windows SharePoint Services Web Services -
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979690(v=office.12).aspx

Call it from js - http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-web-services-with-jquery.aspx

SharePoint Foundation 2010 Managed Client Object Model - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094.aspx

[Setting a Sharepoint Site Theme through a Web Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126274/setting-a-sharepoint-site-theme-through-a-web-service?rq=1)